# laptop crashed now python script is corrupted

Tags: python, encoding, crash

I was working on a python script in spyder and my laptop froze and I had to do a hard restart. When I restarted everything seemed fine except the script I was working on now has strange encoding e.g. what should be an import statement now looks like,

```
@ÐBÂ'Zrr¾"ÈÉÎ±ôí£YÛJOw#Ær   ¾mÄ|¦~Äì,:ë¸6
```

Is there a way to recover my script or is it lost?
I am running linux mint 17 Qiana.
thanks
D

Comment: What's your IDE/text editor and doesn't it keep a backup of the files you work on? Vim for example would have a swap file that can be used to restore what you were working on in case there was a problem.

Comment: What tools are you using to view the file? Would a simple "cat <file.py>" show you something different? Are other files also corrupted?

Comment: I was using spyder (http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/), not sure if it keeps a backup.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look like it might support an autosave feature, but a request for that [has been raised](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2111).

Comment: That's exactly why you put stuff in a local git repo

Answer (score 0):

That's garbage not a weir encoded text file and clearly this is not a programming related question.